# save random numbers generated with awk in a variable

Tags: bash, random, awk

This code is very helpful awk in bash script for generating random numbers.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
# seed
srand()
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
print int(1 + rand() * 1000)
}
}'
```

But it just print random numbers. I whould like save random number(s) in variable(s) and after awk ends, use them.
Is it possible? How?

Comment: use `var=$(command)` to store the output of a command. In this case, you may want to use `var=( $(command) )` to generate an array.

Comment: Why awk? Would it not be easier to use `$((RANDOM % 1000 + 1))`?

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. It works. But all array elements are the same.

Comment: I just tested it doing `r=( $(awk...) )` and then printing with `echo ${r[@]}`. It works fine.

Comment: @Wintermute I experience that RANDOM doesn't generate really random numbers and srand() is better than.

Comment: Neither generates *really* random numbers. Bash's `$RANDOM` has a rather limited range, to be sure, but large enough for this particular case. Hmm...although with the first formula you'd get some bias for the lower values. Perhaps `$((RANDOM * 1000 / 32768 + 1))` would be better, to at least spread it around. Mind you, get a strictly uniform distribution, you'd have to discard values in the overhang (both with `$RANDOM` and awk's `rand()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them in an array which you can reuse later

```
awk 'BEGIN {
srand();
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
rdm[i]=int(1 + rand() * 1000)
}
}
END{
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
print rdm[i]} # reuse them here
}'
```

If you want to reuse them outside awk :

```
rdm=($(awk 'BEGIN {
srand()
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
print int(1 + rand() * 1000)
}
}'))
```

and in bash:

```
for r in ${rdm[*]}; do
   echo $r; # or reuse them here
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash isn't my native language (at least not yet ;), use following code as a clue:

```
# uncomment line if for-loop shows numbers as one item
#IFS=$(echo -en "\n\t\b")

# save to var
A=$(awk 'BEGIN {
# seed
srand()
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
print int(1 + rand() * 1000)
}
}')

# Use in for-loop
for b in $A
do
    echo "Your lucky number is ${b}."
done

# to rolback changes:
#IFS=$(echo -en "\n\t ")
```

May be helpful

[IFS - Internal field separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)

Comment: both of @Krzysiek and fedorqui suggestions work for me. Thanks very much.